# Como criar um build script para compilar o librtmp com o openssl?

Tags: linux, bash, linha-de-comando, openssl, rtmpdump

Estou implementando o projeto [ijkplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer)(*android mediaplayer*) mas estou com dificuldades em adaptar uma compilação automatizada do librtmp(*rtmpdump*).

Tenho o seguinte exemplo abaixo, usado para compilar o OpenSSL no ijkplayer:

**ijkplayer/android/contrib/tools/do-compile-openssl.sh**

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

#--------------------
set -e

if [ -z "$ANDROID_NDK" ]; then
    echo "You must define ANDROID_NDK before starting."
    echo "They must point to your NDK directories.\n"
    exit 1
fi

#--------------------
# common defines
FF_ARCH=$1
if [ -z "$FF_ARCH" ]; then
    echo "You must specific an architecture 'arm, armv7a, x86, ...'.\n"
    exit 1
fi


FF_BUILD_ROOT=`pwd`
FF_ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-9


FF_BUILD_NAME=
FF_SOURCE=
FF_CROSS_PREFIX=

FF_CFG_FLAGS=
FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS=

FF_EXTRA_CFLAGS=
FF_EXTRA_LDFLAGS=



#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] make NDK standalone toolchain"
echo "--------------------"
. ./tools/do-detect-env.sh
FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS=$IJK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS
FF_MAKE_FLAGS=$IJK_MAKE_FLAG
FF_GCC_VER=$IJK_GCC_VER
FF_GCC_64_VER=$IJK_GCC_64_VER


#----- armv7a begin -----
if [ "$FF_ARCH" = "armv7a" ]; then
    FF_BUILD_NAME=openssl-armv7a
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=arm-linux-androideabi
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-${FF_GCC_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="android-armv7"

elif [ "$FF_ARCH" = "armv5" ]; then
    FF_BUILD_NAME=openssl-armv5
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=arm-linux-androideabi
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-${FF_GCC_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="android"

elif [ "$FF_ARCH" = "x86" ]; then
    FF_BUILD_NAME=openssl-x86
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=i686-linux-android
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=x86-${FF_GCC_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="android-x86"

elif [ "$FF_ARCH" = "x86_64" ]; then
    FF_ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21

    FF_BUILD_NAME=openssl-x86_64
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=x86_64-linux-android
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-${FF_GCC_64_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="linux-x86_64"

elif [ "$FF_ARCH" = "arm64" ]; then
    FF_ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21

    FF_BUILD_NAME=openssl-arm64
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=aarch64-linux-android
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-${FF_GCC_64_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="linux-aarch64"

else
    echo "unknown architecture $FF_ARCH";
    exit 1
fi

FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/build/$FF_BUILD_NAME/toolchain

FF_SYSROOT=$FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/sysroot
FF_PREFIX=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/build/$FF_BUILD_NAME/output

mkdir -p $FF_PREFIX
mkdir -p $FF_SYSROOT


#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] make NDK standalone toolchain"
echo "--------------------"
. ./tools/do-detect-env.sh
FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS=$IJK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS
FF_MAKE_FLAGS=$IJK_MAKE_FLAG


FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS="$FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS --install-dir=$FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH"
FF_TOOLCHAIN_TOUCH="$FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/touch"
if [ ! -f "$FF_TOOLCHAIN_TOUCH" ]; then
    $ANDROID_NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh \
        $FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS \
        --platform=$FF_ANDROID_PLATFORM \
        --toolchain=$FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME
    touch $FF_TOOLCHAIN_TOUCH;
fi


#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] check openssl env"
echo "--------------------"
export PATH=$FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/bin:$PATH

export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS=

FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS $COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS"

#--------------------
# Standard options:
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS zlib-dynamic"
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS no-shared"
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS --openssldir=$FF_PREFIX"
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS --cross-compile-prefix=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-"
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS $FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS"

#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] configurate openssl"
echo "--------------------"
cd $FF_SOURCE
#if [ -f "./Makefile" ]; then
#    echo 'reuse configure'
#else
    echo "./Configure $FF_CFG_FLAGS"
    ./Configure $FF_CFG_FLAGS
#        --extra-cflags="$FF_CFLAGS $FF_EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
#        --extra-ldflags="$FF_EXTRA_LDFLAGS"
#fi

#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] compile openssl"
echo "--------------------"
make depend
make $FF_MAKE_FLAGS
make install_sw

#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] link openssl"
echo "--------------------"
```

---

Aqui o arquivo `compile-openssl.sh` que é usado para chamar o arquivo responsável pela compilação, `do-compile-openssl.sh`

**ijkplayer/android/contrib/compile-openssl.sh**

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

#----------
export ANDROID_NDK="/run/media/root/linux/workspace/android-ndk-r11c"

UNI_BUILD_ROOT=`pwd`
FF_TARGET=$1
set -e
set +x

FF_ACT_ARCHS_32="armv5 armv7a x86"
FF_ACT_ARCHS_64="armv5 armv7a arm64 x86 x86_64"
FF_ACT_ARCHS_ALL=$FF_ACT_ARCHS_64

echo_archs() {
    echo "===================="
    echo "[*] check archs"
    echo "===================="
    echo "FF_ALL_ARCHS = $FF_ACT_ARCHS_ALL"
    echo "FF_ACT_ARCHS = $*"
    echo ""
}

echo_usage() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "  compile-openssl.sh armv5|armv7a|arm64|x86|x86_64"
    echo "  compile-openssl.sh all|all32"
    echo "  compile-openssl.sh all64"
    echo "  compile-openssl.sh clean"
    echo "  compile-openssl.sh check"
    exit 1
}

echo_nextstep_help() {
    #----------
    echo ""
    echo "--------------------"
    echo "[*] Finished"
    echo "--------------------"
    echo "# to continue to build ffmpeg, run script below,"
    echo "sh compile-ffmpeg.sh "
    echo "# to continue to build ijkplayer, run script below,"
    echo "sh compile-ijk.sh "
}

#----------
case "$FF_TARGET" in
    "")
        echo_archs armv7a
        sh tools/do-compile-openssl.sh armv7a
    ;;
    armv5|armv7a|arm64|x86|x86_64)
        echo_archs $FF_TARGET
        sh tools/do-compile-openssl.sh $FF_TARGET
        echo_nextstep_help
    ;;
    all32)
        echo_archs $FF_ACT_ARCHS_32
        for ARCH in $FF_ACT_ARCHS_32
        do
            sh tools/do-compile-openssl.sh $ARCH
        done
        echo_nextstep_help
    ;;
    all|all64)
        echo_archs $FF_ACT_ARCHS_64
        for ARCH in $FF_ACT_ARCHS_64
        do
            sh tools/do-compile-openssl.sh $ARCH
        done
        echo_nextstep_help
    ;;
    clean)
        echo_archs FF_ACT_ARCHS_64
        for ARCH in $FF_ACT_ARCHS_ALL
        do
            if [ -d openssl-$ARCH ]; then
                cd openssl-$ARCH && git clean -xdf && cd -
            fi
        done
        rm -rf ./build/openssl-*
    ;;
    check)
        echo_archs FF_ACT_ARCHS_ALL
    ;;
    *)
        echo_usage
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Até agora fiz as seguintes modificações para a adaptação da compilação do librtmp:

**Arquivo `do-compile-openssl.sh` modificado para `do-compile-librtmp.sh`**

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

#--------------------
set -e

if [ -z "$ANDROID_NDK" ]; then
    echo "You must define ANDROID_NDK before starting."
    echo "They must point to your NDK directories.\n"
    exit 1
fi

#--------------------
# common defines
FF_ARCH=$1
if [ -z "$FF_ARCH" ]; then
    echo "You must specific an architecture 'arm, armv7a, x86, ...'.\n"
    exit 1
fi


FF_BUILD_ROOT=`pwd`
FF_ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-9


FF_BUILD_NAME=
FF_SOURCE=
FF_CROSS_PREFIX=

FF_CFG_FLAGS=
FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS=

FF_EXTRA_CFLAGS=
FF_EXTRA_LDFLAGS=



#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] make NDK standalone toolchain"
echo "--------------------"
. ./tools/do-detect-env.sh
FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS=$IJK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS
FF_MAKE_FLAGS=$IJK_MAKE_FLAG
FF_GCC_VER=$IJK_GCC_VER
FF_GCC_64_VER=$IJK_GCC_64_VER


#----- armv7a begin -----
if [ "$FF_ARCH" = "armv7a" ]; then
    FF_BUILD_NAME=librtmp-armv7a
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=arm-linux-androideabi
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-${FF_GCC_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="android-armv7"

elif [ "$FF_ARCH" = "armv5" ]; then
    FF_BUILD_NAME=librtmp-armv5
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=arm-linux-androideabi
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-${FF_GCC_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="android"

elif [ "$FF_ARCH" = "x86" ]; then
    FF_BUILD_NAME=librtmp-x86
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=i686-linux-android
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=x86-${FF_GCC_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="android-x86"

elif [ "$FF_ARCH" = "x86_64" ]; then
    FF_ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21

    FF_BUILD_NAME=librtmp-x86_64
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=x86_64-linux-android
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-${FF_GCC_64_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="linux-x86_64"

elif [ "$FF_ARCH" = "arm64" ]; then
    FF_ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21

    FF_BUILD_NAME=librtmp-arm64
    FF_SOURCE=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/$FF_BUILD_NAME

    FF_CROSS_PREFIX=aarch64-linux-android
    FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-${FF_GCC_64_VER}

    FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS="linux-aarch64"

else
    echo "unknown architecture $FF_ARCH";
    exit 1
fi

FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/build/$FF_BUILD_NAME/toolchain

FF_SYSROOT=$FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/sysroot
FF_PREFIX=$FF_BUILD_ROOT/build/$FF_BUILD_NAME/output

mkdir -p $FF_PREFIX
mkdir -p $FF_SYSROOT


#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] make NDK standalone toolchain"
echo "--------------------"
. ./tools/do-detect-env.sh
FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS=$IJK_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS
FF_MAKE_FLAGS=$IJK_MAKE_FLAG


FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS="$FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS --install-dir=$FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH"
FF_TOOLCHAIN_TOUCH="$FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/touch"
if [ ! -f "$FF_TOOLCHAIN_TOUCH" ]; then
    $ANDROID_NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh \
        $FF_MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FLAGS \
        --platform=$FF_ANDROID_PLATFORM \
        --toolchain=$FF_TOOLCHAIN_NAME
    touch $FF_TOOLCHAIN_TOUCH;
fi


#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] check librtmp env"
echo "--------------------"
export PATH=$FF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/bin:$PATH

export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS=

FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS $COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS"

#--------------------
# Standard options:
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS zlib-dynamic"
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS no-shared"
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS --openssldir=$FF_PREFIX"
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS --cross-compile-prefix=${FF_CROSS_PREFIX}-"
FF_CFG_FLAGS="$FF_CFG_FLAGS $FF_PLATFORM_CFG_FLAGS"

#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] configurate librtmp"
echo "--------------------"
cd $FF_SOURCE
#if [ -f "./Makefile" ]; then
#    echo 'reuse configure'
#else
    echo "./Configure $FF_CFG_FLAGS"
    ./Configure $FF_CFG_FLAGS
#        --extra-cflags="$FF_CFLAGS $FF_EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
#        --extra-ldflags="$FF_EXTRA_LDFLAGS"
#fi

#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] compile librtmp"
echo "--------------------"
make depend
make $FF_MAKE_FLAGS
make install_sw

#--------------------
echo ""
echo "--------------------"
echo "[*] link librtmp"
echo "--------------------"
```

Manualmente posso executar a compilação em *standalone* do *librtmp* com o *OpenSSL* com o seguinte comando `/run/media/root/linux/workspace/android-ndk-r11c/ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-14 TARGET_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.` usando os [arquivos do rtmpdump](https://github.com/PlayOrion/Android-rtmpdump) abaixo.

**rtmpdump/Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/,$(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
        librtmp \
    ))

ifeq($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), armeabi)
    SSL := ../../v_openssl/OpenSSL-1.0.2g_armeabi
endif

ifeq($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), armeabi-v7a)
    SSL := ../../v_openssl/OpenSSL-1.0.2g_armeabi-v7a
endif

ifeq($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), x86)
    SSL := ../../v_openssl/OpenSSL-1.0.2g_x86
endif

#SSL := ~/SSL
ifndef SSL
$(error "You must define SSL before starting")
endif

include $(subdirs)
```

---

**rtmpdump/Makefile**

```
VERSION=v2.4

prefix=/usr/local

CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
LD=$(CROSS_COMPILE)ld

SYS=posix
#SYS=mingw

CRYPTO=OPENSSL
#CRYPTO=POLARSSL
#CRYPTO=GNUTLS
LIBZ=-lz
LIB_GNUTLS=-lgnutls -lhogweed -lnettle -lgmp $(LIBZ)
LIB_OPENSSL=-lssl -lcrypto $(LIBZ)
LIB_POLARSSL=-lpolarssl $(LIBZ)
CRYPTO_LIB=$(LIB_$(CRYPTO))
DEF_=-DNO_CRYPTO
CRYPTO_DEF=$(DEF_$(CRYPTO))

DEF=-DRTMPDUMP_VERSION=\"$(VERSION)\" $(CRYPTO_DEF) $(XDEF)
OPT=-O2
CFLAGS=-Wall $(XCFLAGS) $(INC) $(DEF) $(OPT)
LDFLAGS=-Wall $(XLDFLAGS)

bindir=$(prefix)/bin
sbindir=$(prefix)/sbin
mandir=$(prefix)/man

BINDIR=$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
SBINDIR=$(DESTDIR)$(sbindir)
MANDIR=$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)

LIBS_posix=
LIBS_darwin=
LIBS_mingw=-lws2_32 -lwinmm -lgdi32
LIB_RTMP=-Llibrtmp -lrtmp
LIBS=$(LIB_RTMP) $(CRYPTO_LIB) $(LIBS_$(SYS)) $(XLIBS)

THREADLIB_posix=-lpthread
THREADLIB_darwin=-lpthread
THREADLIB_mingw=
THREADLIB=$(THREADLIB_$(SYS))
SLIBS=$(THREADLIB) $(LIBS)

LIBRTMP=librtmp/librtmp.a
INCRTMP=librtmp/rtmp_sys.h librtmp/rtmp.h librtmp/log.h librtmp/amf.h

EXT_posix=
EXT_darwin=
EXT_mingw=.exe
EXT=$(EXT_$(SYS))

PROGS=rtmpdump rtmpgw rtmpsrv rtmpsuck

all:    $(LIBRTMP) $(PROGS)

$(PROGS): $(LIBRTMP)

install:    $(PROGS)
    -mkdir -p $(BINDIR) $(SBINDIR) $(MANDIR)/man1 $(MANDIR)/man8
    cp rtmpdump$(EXT) $(BINDIR)
    cp rtmpgw$(EXT) rtmpsrv$(EXT) rtmpsuck$(EXT) $(SBINDIR)
    cp rtmpdump.1 $(MANDIR)/man1
    cp rtmpgw.8 $(MANDIR)/man8
    @cd librtmp; $(MAKE) install

clean:
    rm -f *.o rtmpdump$(EXT) rtmpgw$(EXT) rtmpsrv$(EXT) rtmpsuck$(EXT)
    @cd librtmp; $(MAKE) clean

FORCE:

$(LIBRTMP): FORCE
    @cd librtmp; $(MAKE) all

rtmpdump: rtmpdump.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@$(EXT) $@.o $(LIBS)

rtmpsrv: rtmpsrv.o thread.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@$(EXT) $@.o thread.o $(SLIBS)

rtmpsuck: rtmpsuck.o thread.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@$(EXT) $@.o thread.o $(SLIBS)

rtmpgw: rtmpgw.o thread.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@$(EXT) $@.o thread.o $(SLIBS)

rtmpgw.o: rtmpgw.c $(INCRTMP) Makefile
rtmpdump.o: rtmpdump.c $(INCRTMP) Makefile
rtmpsrv.o: rtmpsrv.c $(INCRTMP) Makefile
rtmpsuck.o: rtmpsuck.c $(INCRTMP) Makefile
thread.o: thread.c thread.h
```

---

**rtmpdump/jni/Application.mk**

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_ABI := all
APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(shell pwd)
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/Android.mk
```

---

**rtmpdump/librtmp/Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH)/librtmp \
    $(SSL)/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    amf.c \
    hashswf.c \
    log.c \
    parseurl.c \
    rtmp.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(SSL)/include -DUSE_OPENSSL
#LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(SSL)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
#Modificado para OpenSSL 1.0.2g stand alone build
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(SSL) 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lssl -lcrypto -lz

LOCAL_MODULE := librtmp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

**rtmpdump/librtmp/Makefile**

```
VERSION=v2.4

prefix=/usr/local

incdir=$(prefix)/include/librtmp
bindir=$(prefix)/bin
libdir=$(prefix)/lib
mandir=$(prefix)/man
BINDIR=$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
INCDIR=$(DESTDIR)$(incdir)
LIBDIR=$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
MANDIR=$(DESTDIR)$(mandir)

CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
LD=$(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
AR=$(CROSS_COMPILE)ar

SYS=posix
CRYPTO=OPENSSL
#CRYPTO=GNUTLS
DEF_POLARSSL=-DUSE_POLARSSL
DEF_OPENSSL=-DUSE_OPENSSL
DEF_GNUTLS=-DUSE_GNUTLS
DEF_=-DNO_CRYPTO
REQ_GNUTLS=gnutls
REQ_OPENSSL=libssl,libcrypto
LIBZ=-lz
LIBS_posix=
LIBS_darwin=
LIBS_mingw=-lws2_32 -lwinmm -lgdi32
LIB_GNUTLS=-lgnutls -lhogweed -lnettle -lgmp $(LIBZ)
LIB_OPENSSL=-lssl -lcrypto $(LIBZ)
LIB_POLARSSL=-lpolarssl $(LIBZ)
PRIVATE_LIBS=$(LIBS_$(SYS))
CRYPTO_LIB=$(LIB_$(CRYPTO)) $(PRIVATE_LIBS)
CRYPTO_REQ=$(REQ_$(CRYPTO))
CRYPTO_DEF=$(DEF_$(CRYPTO))

SO_VERSION=0
SOX_posix=so
SOX_darwin=dylib
SOX_mingw=dll
SOX=$(SOX_$(SYS))
SO_posix=.$(SOX).$(SO_VERSION)
SO_darwin=.$(SO_VERSION).$(SOX)
SO_mingw=-$(SO_VERSION).$(SOX)
SO_EXT=$(SO_$(SYS))

SODIR_posix=$(LIBDIR)
SODIR_darwin=$(LIBDIR)
SODIR_mingw=$(BINDIR)
SODIR=$(SODIR_$(SYS))

SO_LDFLAGS_posix=-shared -Wl,-soname,$@
SO_LDFLAGS_darwin=-dynamiclib -twolevel_namespace -undefined dynamic_lookup \
    -fno-common -headerpad_max_install_names -install_name $(libdir)/$@
SO_LDFLAGS_mingw=-shared -Wl,--out-implib,librtmp.dll.a
SO_LDFLAGS=$(SO_LDFLAGS_$(SYS))

INSTALL_IMPLIB_posix=
INSTALL_IMPLIB_darwin=
INSTALL_IMPLIB_mingw=cp librtmp.dll.a $(LIBDIR)
INSTALL_IMPLIB=$(INSTALL_IMPLIB_$(SYS))

SHARED=yes
SODEF_yes=-fPIC
SOLIB_yes=librtmp$(SO_EXT)
SOINST_yes=install_so
SO_DEF=$(SODEF_$(SHARED))
SO_LIB=$(SOLIB_$(SHARED))
SO_INST=$(SOINST_$(SHARED))

DEF=-DRTMPDUMP_VERSION=\"$(VERSION)\" $(CRYPTO_DEF) $(XDEF)
OPT=-O2
CFLAGS=-Wall $(XCFLAGS) $(INC) $(DEF) $(OPT) $(SO_DEF)
LDFLAGS=$(XLDFLAGS)


OBJS=rtmp.o log.o amf.o hashswf.o parseurl.o

all:    librtmp.a $(SO_LIB)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.a *.$(SOX) *$(SO_EXT) librtmp.pc

librtmp.a: $(OBJS)
    $(AR) rs $@ $?

librtmp$(SO_EXT): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(SO_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $> $(CRYPTO_LIB)
    ln -sf $@ librtmp.$(SOX)

log.o: log.c log.h Makefile
rtmp.o: rtmp.c rtmp.h rtmp_sys.h handshake.h dh.h log.h amf.h Makefile
amf.o: amf.c amf.h bytes.h log.h Makefile
hashswf.o: hashswf.c http.h rtmp.h rtmp_sys.h Makefile
parseurl.o: parseurl.c rtmp.h rtmp_sys.h log.h Makefile

librtmp.pc: librtmp.pc.in Makefile
    sed -e "s;@prefix@;$(prefix);" -e "s;@libdir@;$(libdir);" \
        -e "s;@VERSION@;$(VERSION);" \
        -e "s;@CRYPTO_REQ@;$(CRYPTO_REQ);" \
        -e "s;@PRIVATE_LIBS@;$(PRIVATE_LIBS);" librtmp.pc.in > $@

install:    install_base $(SO_INST)

install_base:   librtmp.a librtmp.pc
    -mkdir -p $(INCDIR) $(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig $(MANDIR)/man3 $(SODIR)
    cp amf.h http.h log.h rtmp.h $(INCDIR)
    cp librtmp.a $(LIBDIR)
    cp librtmp.pc $(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig
    cp librtmp.3 $(MANDIR)/man3

install_so: librtmp$(SO_EXT)
    cp librtmp$(SO_EXT) $(SODIR)
    $(INSTALL_IMPLIB)
    cd $(SODIR); ln -sf librtmp$(SO_EXT) librtmp.$(SOX)
```

A grande questão é: Como vou modificar esses arquivos(`do-compile-librtmp.sh`) para que ao executar o `./compile-librtmp.sh all` sejam compilados automaticamente as arquiteturas definidas nele junto com o *OpenSSL*?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa replicar o compile-openssl.sh, apenas modificando pro arquivo que vc criou "do-compile-librtmp.sh"

```
UNI_BUILD_ROOT=`pwd`
FF_TARGET=$1
set -e
set +x

FF_ACT_ARCHS_32="armv5 armv7a x86"
FF_ACT_ARCHS_64="armv5 armv7a arm64 x86 x86_64"
FF_ACT_ARCHS_ALL=$FF_ACT_ARCHS_64

echo_archs() {
    echo "===================="
    echo "[*] check archs"
    echo "===================="
    echo "FF_ALL_ARCHS = $FF_ACT_ARCHS_ALL"
    echo "FF_ACT_ARCHS = $*"
    echo ""
}

echo_usage() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "  compile-librtmp.sh armv5|armv7a|arm64|x86|x86_64"
    echo "  compile-librtmp.sh all|all32"
    echo "  compile-librtmp.sh all64"
    echo "  compile-librtmp.sh clean"
    echo "  compile-librtmp.sh check"
    exit 1
}

echo_nextstep_help() {
    #----------
    echo ""
    echo "--------------------"
    echo "[*] Finished"
    echo "--------------------"
    echo "# to continue to build ffmpeg, run script below,"
    echo "sh compile-ffmpeg.sh "
    echo "# to continue to build ijkplayer, run script below,"
    echo "sh compile-ijk.sh "
}

#----------
case "$FF_TARGET" in
    "")
        echo_archs armv7a
        sh tools/do-compile-librtmp.sh armv7a
    ;;
    armv5|armv7a|arm64|x86|x86_64)
        echo_archs $FF_TARGET
        sh tools/do-compile-librtmp.sh $FF_TARGET
        echo_nextstep_help
    ;;
    all32)
        echo_archs $FF_ACT_ARCHS_32
        for ARCH in $FF_ACT_ARCHS_32
        do
            sh tools/do-compile-librtmp.sh $ARCH
        done
        echo_nextstep_help
    ;;
    all|all64)
        echo_archs $FF_ACT_ARCHS_64
        for ARCH in $FF_ACT_ARCHS_64
        do
            sh tools/do-compile-librtmp.sh $ARCH
        done
        echo_nextstep_help
    ;;
    clean)
        echo_archs FF_ACT_ARCHS_64
        for ARCH in $FF_ACT_ARCHS_ALL
        do
            if [ -d librtmp-$ARCH ]; then
                cd librtmp-$ARCH && git clean -xdf && cd -
            fi
        done
        rm -rf ./build/librtmp-*
    ;;
    check)
        echo_archs FF_ACT_ARCHS_ALL
    ;;
    *)
        echo_usage
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Não consegui compilar usando um build script, optei pela compilação manual, esses scripts são bons, mas apenas para o ijkplayer, usá-los em outros projetos é bem complicado. O jeito é compilar manualmente com o build-ndk... pois o librtmp usa os arquivos Makefile para a configuração, e passar isso para um build script é extremamente complicado. Agradeço a ajuda.